# Updating a JLabel from another class not working

Tags: java, jlabel, getter-setter

I am trying to update a jlabel from another class. I've pasted my code below.

```
Class A {

public void setNetAmount(String s){
    jLabel51.setText(s);
}
public void setDis_percentage(String s){
    jLabel53.setText(s);
}
public void setDiscount(String s){
    jLabel55.setText(s);
}
public void setAdjustment(String s){
    jLabel57.setText(s);
}

}

Class B{
public void SetData(){
new A.setNetAmount(""+netAmount);
new A.setDis_percentage(""+dis_percentage);
new A.setDiscount(""+discount);
new A.setAdjustment(""+adjustment);    
}
}
```

I am calling the `SetData()` method in Class A.

```
public void getData(){
B b = new b();
b.setData();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ? It is not working at all. Is there any issue of EDT? Please help.

Comment: It's likely that either the reference you are updating is not the same as the reference on the screen or you've not added the able to the screen

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep invoking "new A". This creates a new instance of class A.

Not really sure why you have a class B to invoke a few methods from class A, but if you use this approach then you would need to pass a reference of class A the your class B method.

Something like:

```
public class B
{
    public void setData(A a)
    {
        a.setAmount(...);
        a.setPercentage(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then when you invoke the method in your class A you would use:

```
B b = new B();
b.setData(this);
```

Although this is a really strange design.

Comment: Dear @camickr, This works fine. Sorry. but how can I change the 'JLabel' text within 'Class B'.